# how to debug nativescript app in chrome browser and view output in chrome

Tags: angular, nativescript

Hello I m new to NativeScript, as per the docs available on NativeScript site, I had created a demo app with NativeSript + Angular and deployed that on device but for debugging i want it to run on web browser like chrome to get the view of app and debug. As per the docs i m able to debug it in chrome but I can get the view of app to run in chrome. Is there some way to do that.

Comment: You will have to run the application on an emulator or device. You cannot use chrome to view the application.

Comment: ok but if i want to inspect an element then how will I do it.

Comment: you can run the debugger with the commands `tns debug android` or `tns debug ios` both of those will give you access to the chrome debugger. for iOS it opens up it's own instance. With Android it will give you a link to paste into your browser window.

Comment: Yes I know that way but if I want to inspect some elements their styles in chrome or some other browser, that I want to know, is there some way or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go.

```
tns debug ios --chrome
```

You will then want to pay close attention to your terminal and find the following line.

> To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:

[image]

Open up your browser and copy and paste that path and you will get access to the developer tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responce

Comment: Instead of 'tanks', you can accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Enter following Command in terminal

```
tns debug android
```

check terminal and find following URL

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000
```

copy above url and paste in crome and start debugging